# MathJax SVG not validating

Tags: python, svg, mathjax

I have an SVG of a math equation generated by MathJax. I want to convert this SVG into a PNG. The problem is that I need to somehow get the SVG from the webpage into a self-contained SVG I can run through a library.

The problem is I don't know how to stitch the SVG up. Here is an example of a math equation:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width: 17ex; height: 2.556ex; vertical-align: -0.667ex; margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 0px; " viewbox="0 -861.7994854101626 7312.533368943652 1097.702786738219">
    <g stroke="black" fill="black" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)">
        <use xlink:href="#MJMATHI-79"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-3D" x="779" y="0"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMATHI-61" x="1840" y="0"></use>
        <g transform="translate(2374,0)">
            <use xlink:href="#MJMATHI-78"></use>
            <use transform="scale(0.7071067811865476)" xlink:href="#MJMAIN-32" x="816" y="513"></use>
        </g>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-2B" x="3630" y="0"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMATHI-62" x="4636" y="0"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMATHI-78" x="5070" y="0"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-2B" x="5869" y="0"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#MJMATHI-63" x="6874" y="0"></use>
    </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, it uses `<use>` elements. I found the paths the `<use>` refers to in this `<div>`:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 1px; width: auto; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; line-height: normal; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: normal; ">
    <div id="MathJax_SVG_Hidden"></div>
    <svg>
        <defs id="MathJax_SVG_glyphs">
            <path id="MJMATHI-79" stroke-width="10" d="M21 287Q21 301 36 335T84 406T158 442Q199 442 224 419T250 355Q248 336 247 334Q247 331 231 288T198 191T182 105Q182 62 196 45T238 27Q261 27 281 38T312 61T339 94Q339 95 344 114T358 173T377 247Q415 397 419 404Q432 431 462 431Q475 431 483 424T494 412T496 403Q496 390 447 193T391 -23Q363 -106 294 -155T156 -205Q111 -205 77 -183T43 -117Q43 -95 50 -80T69 -58T89 -48T106 -45Q150 -45 150 -87Q150 -107 138 -122T115 -142T102 -147L99 -148Q101 -153 118 -160T152 -167H160Q177 -167 186 -165Q219 -156 247 -127T290 -65T313 -9T321 21L315 17Q309 13 296 6T270 -6Q250 -11 231 -11Q185 -11 150 11T104 82Q103 89 103 113Q103 170 138 262T173 379Q173 380 173 381Q173 390 173 393T169 400T158 404H154Q131 404 112 385T82 344T65 302T57 280Q55 278 41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMAIN-3D" stroke-width="10" d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMATHI-61" stroke-width="10" d="M33 157Q33 258 109 349T280 441Q331 441 370 392Q386 422 416 422Q429 422 439 414T449 394Q449 381 412 234T374 68Q374 43 381 35T402 26Q411 27 422 35Q443 55 463 131Q469 151 473 152Q475 153 483 153H487Q506 153 506 144Q506 138 501 117T481 63T449 13Q436 0 417 -8Q409 -10 393 -10Q359 -10 336 5T306 36L300 51Q299 52 296 50Q294 48 292 46Q233 -10 172 -10Q117 -10 75 30T33 157ZM351 328Q351 334 346 350T323 385T277 405Q242 405 210 374T160 293Q131 214 119 129Q119 126 119 118T118 106Q118 61 136 44T179 26Q217 26 254 59T298 110Q300 114 325 217T351 328Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMATHI-78" stroke-width="10" d="M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMAIN-32" stroke-width="10" d="M109 429Q82 429 66 447T50 491Q50 562 103 614T235 666Q326 666 387 610T449 465Q449 422 429 383T381 315T301 241Q265 210 201 149L142 93L218 92Q375 92 385 97Q392 99 409 186V189H449V186Q448 183 436 95T421 3V0H50V19V31Q50 38 56 46T86 81Q115 113 136 137Q145 147 170 174T204 211T233 244T261 278T284 308T305 340T320 369T333 401T340 431T343 464Q343 527 309 573T212 619Q179 619 154 602T119 569T109 550Q109 549 114 549Q132 549 151 535T170 489Q170 464 154 447T109 429Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMAIN-2B" stroke-width="10" d="M56 237T56 250T70 270H369V420L370 570Q380 583 389 583Q402 583 409 568V270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H409V-68Q401 -82 391 -82H389H387Q375 -82 369 -68V230H70Q56 237 56 250Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMATHI-62" stroke-width="10" d="M73 647Q73 657 77 670T89 683Q90 683 161 688T234 694Q246 694 246 685T212 542Q204 508 195 472T180 418L176 399Q176 396 182 402Q231 442 283 442Q345 442 383 396T422 280Q422 169 343 79T173 -11Q123 -11 82 27T40 150V159Q40 180 48 217T97 414Q147 611 147 623T109 637Q104 637 101 637H96Q86 637 83 637T76 640T73 647ZM336 325V331Q336 405 275 405Q258 405 240 397T207 376T181 352T163 330L157 322L136 236Q114 150 114 114Q114 66 138 42Q154 26 178 26Q211 26 245 58Q270 81 285 114T318 219Q336 291 336 325Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMATHI-63" stroke-width="10" d="M34 159Q34 268 120 355T306 442Q362 442 394 418T427 355Q427 326 408 306T360 285Q341 285 330 295T319 325T330 359T352 380T366 386H367Q367 388 361 392T340 400T306 404Q276 404 249 390Q228 381 206 359Q162 315 142 235T121 119Q121 73 147 50Q169 26 205 26H209Q321 26 394 111Q403 121 406 121Q410 121 419 112T429 98T420 83T391 55T346 25T282 0T202 -11Q127 -11 81 37T34 159Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMAIN-2212" stroke-width="10" d="M84 237T84 250T98 270H679Q694 262 694 250T679 230H98Q84 237 84 250Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMAIN-B1" stroke-width="10" d="M56 320T56 333T70 353H369V502Q369 651 371 655Q376 666 388 666Q402 666 405 654T409 596V500V353H707Q722 345 722 333Q722 320 707 313H409V40H707Q722 32 722 20T707 0H70Q56 7 56 20T70 40H369V313H70Q56 320 56 333Z"></path>
            <path id="MJMAIN-34" stroke-width="10" d="M462 0Q444 3 333 3Q217 3 199 0H190V46H221Q241 46 248 46T265 48T279 53T286 61Q287 63 287 115V165H28V211L179 442Q332 674 334 675Q336 677 355 677H373L379 671V211H471V165H379V114Q379 73 379 66T385 54Q393 47 442 46H471V0H462ZM293 211V545L74 212L183 211H293Z"></path>
            <path id="MJSZ1-221A" stroke-width="10" d="M263 249Q264 249 315 130T417 -108T470 -228L725 302Q981 837 982 839Q989 850 1001 850Q1008 850 1013 844T1020 832V826L741 243Q645 43 540 -176Q479 -303 469 -324T453 -348Q449 -350 436 -350L424 -349L315 -96Q206 156 205 156L171 130Q138 104 137 104L111 130L263 249Z"></path>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I tried just inserting the `<defs>` element into the original math equation like this:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​1999/​xlink" style=​"width:​ 17.036ex;​ height:​ 2.571ex;​ vertical-align:​ -0.643ex;​ margin-top:​ 1px;​ margin-right:​ 0px;​ margin-bottom:​ 1px;​ margin-left:​ 0px; ​" viewBox=​"0 -862.5736817556461 7312.533368943652 1099.251179429186">​
    <defs id=​"MathJax_SVG_glyphs">​
    <path id=​"MJMATHI-79" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M21 287Q21 301 36 335T84 406T158 442Q199 442 224 419T250 355Q248 336 247 334Q247 331 231 288T198 191T182 105Q182 62 196 45T238 27Q261 27 281 38T312 61T339 94Q339 95 344 114T358 173T377 247Q415 397 419 404Q432 431 462 431Q475 431 483 424T494 412T496 403Q496 390 447 193T391 -23Q363 -106 294 -155T156 -205Q111 -205 77 -183T43 -117Q43 -95 50 -80T69 -58T89 -48T106 -45Q150 -45 150 -87Q150 -107 138 -122T115 -142T102 -147L99 -148Q101 -153 118 -160T152 -167H160Q177 -167 186 -165Q219 -156 247 -127T290 -65T313 -9T321 21L315 17Q309 13 296 6T270 -6Q250 -11 231 -11Q185 -11 150 11T104 82Q103 89 103 113Q103 170 138 262T173 379Q173 380 173 381Q173 390 173 393T169 400T158 404H154Q131 404 112 385T82 344T65 302T57 280Q55 278 41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMAIN-3D" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMATHI-61" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M33 157Q33 258 109 349T280 441Q331 441 370 392Q386 422 416 422Q429 422 439 414T449 394Q449 381 412 234T374 68Q374 43 381 35T402 26Q411 27 422 35Q443 55 463 131Q469 151 473 152Q475 153 483 153H487Q506 153 506 144Q506 138 501 117T481 63T449 13Q436 0 417 -8Q409 -10 393 -10Q359 -10 336 5T306 36L300 51Q299 52 296 50Q294 48 292 46Q233 -10 172 -10Q117 -10 75 30T33 157ZM351 328Q351 334 346 350T323 385T277 405Q242 405 210 374T160 293Q131 214 119 129Q119 126 119 118T118 106Q118 61 136 44T179 26Q217 26 254 59T298 110Q300 114 325 217T351 328Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMATHI-78" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMAIN-32" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M109 429Q82 429 66 447T50 491Q50 562 103 614T235 666Q326 666 387 610T449 465Q449 422 429 383T381 315T301 241Q265 210 201 149L142 93L218 92Q375 92 385 97Q392 99 409 186V189H449V186Q448 183 436 95T421 3V0H50V19V31Q50 38 56 46T86 81Q115 113 136 137Q145 147 170 174T204 211T233 244T261 278T284 308T305 340T320 369T333 401T340 431T343 464Q343 527 309 573T212 619Q179 619 154 602T119 569T109 550Q109 549 114 549Q132 549 151 535T170 489Q170 464 154 447T109 429Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMAIN-2B" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M56 237T56 250T70 270H369V420L370 570Q380 583 389 583Q402 583 409 568V270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H409V-68Q401 -82 391 -82H389H387Q375 -82 369 -68V230H70Q56 237 56 250Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMATHI-62" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M73 647Q73 657 77 670T89 683Q90 683 161 688T234 694Q246 694 246 685T212 542Q204 508 195 472T180 418L176 399Q176 396 182 402Q231 442 283 442Q345 442 383 396T422 280Q422 169 343 79T173 -11Q123 -11 82 27T40 150V159Q40 180 48 217T97 414Q147 611 147 623T109 637Q104 637 101 637H96Q86 637 83 637T76 640T73 647ZM336 325V331Q336 405 275 405Q258 405 240 397T207 376T181 352T163 330L157 322L136 236Q114 150 114 114Q114 66 138 42Q154 26 178 26Q211 26 245 58Q270 81 285 114T318 219Q336 291 336 325Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMATHI-63" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M34 159Q34 268 120 355T306 442Q362 442 394 418T427 355Q427 326 408 306T360 285Q341 285 330 295T319 325T330 359T352 380T366 386H367Q367 388 361 392T340 400T306 404Q276 404 249 390Q228 381 206 359Q162 315 142 235T121 119Q121 73 147 50Q169 26 205 26H209Q321 26 394 111Q403 121 406 121Q410 121 419 112T429 98T420 83T391 55T346 25T282 0T202 -11Q127 -11 81 37T34 159Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMAIN-2212" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M84 237T84 250T98 270H679Q694 262 694 250T679 230H98Q84 237 84 250Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMAIN-B1" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M56 320T56 333T70 353H369V502Q369 651 371 655Q376 666 388 666Q402 666 405 654T409 596V500V353H707Q722 345 722 333Q722 320 707 313H409V40H707Q722 32 722 20T707 0H70Q56 7 56 20T70 40H369V313H70Q56 320 56 333Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJMAIN-34" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M462 0Q444 3 333 3Q217 3 199 0H190V46H221Q241 46 248 46T265 48T279 53T286 61Q287 63 287 115V165H28V211L179 442Q332 674 334 675Q336 677 355 677H373L379 671V211H471V165H379V114Q379 73 379 66T385 54Q393 47 442 46H471V0H462ZM293 211V545L74 212L183 211H293Z">​</path>​
    <path id=​"MJSZ1-221A" stroke-width=​"10" d=​"M263 249Q264 249 315 130T417 -108T470 -228L725 302Q981 837 982 839Q989 850 1001 850Q1008 850 1013 844T1020 832V826L741 243Q645 43 540 -176Q479 -303 469 -324T453 -348Q449 -350 436 -350L424 -349L315 -96Q206 156 205 156L171 130Q138 104 137 104L111 130L263 249Z">​</path>​
    </defs>​
    <g stroke=​"black" fill=​"black" stroke-width=​"0" transform=​"matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)​">​
        <use href=​"#MJMATHI-79">​</use>​
        <use href=​"#MJMAIN-3D" x=​"779" y=​"0">​</use>​
        <use href=​"#MJMATHI-61" x=​"1840" y=​"0">​</use>​
    <g transform=​"translate(2374,0)​">​
        <use href=​"#MJMATHI-78">​</use>​
        <use transform=​"scale(0.7071067811865476)​" href=​"#MJMAIN-32" x=​"816" y=​"513">​</use>​
    </g>​
        <use href=​"#MJMAIN-2B" x=​"3630" y=​"0">​</use>​
        <use href=​"#MJMATHI-62" x=​"4636" y=​"0">​</use>​
        <use href=​"#MJMATHI-78" x=​"5070" y=​"0">​</use>​
        <use href=​"#MJMAIN-2B" x=​"5869" y=​"0">​</use>​
        <use href=​"#MJMATHI-63" x=​"6874" y=​"0">​</use>​
    </g>​
</svg>
```

But it won't display. I got a Notepad++ plugin to validate my SVG and it says the following

```
XML Parsing error at line 1:
Extra Content at the end of the document
```

I don't know what this is referring to. I tried looking around, but I'm not very experienced concerning SVGs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an character encoding issue to me.  For instance, UTF-8 or UTF-16 being read as ASCII.  If you look at the file in a hex editor you might find there are extra characters in there.

If your text editor has a "show control characters" option, try turning it on.  You can then delete them.  Or your editor may have a encoding conversion feature.

*Update:*

Ok. I C&Ped your file and had to do the following things to fix it:

1. Remove extraneous control characters.
2. Add SVG namespace to the `<svg>` tag. This is needed for standalone files.
3. Added `xlink:` namespace qualifier to `<use>` elements.

Updated file here: http://jsfiddle.net/ywzwS/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didn't even think it would have control characters inside. I got a hex editor on it myself to convince myself, but apparently there were zero-width spaces in it (don't use Webkit's inspector to try and extract SVGs). Yes, MathJax was designed for online purposes, but you think they wouldn't forget the `xlink:` qualifier. Again, thanks for your help.